# Cross-browser spec for canvas pixel data?

Tags: javascript, canvas, typed-arrays

Does anyone happen to know how far back the current canvas pixel-data spec goes in various browsers?  And if "not that far", what the previous spec(s) were?

When you call or push pixels, you get / send:

```
ImageData
  data:   Uint8ClampedArray
  width:  Number
  height: Number
```

But I know that it used to just be:

```
{
  data:   Array
  width:  Number
  height: Number
}
```

So if I'm *generating* ImageData, how do I detect what I need to generate?  Is `ImageData && Uint8ClampedArray` sufficient?  And do I *immediately* fall back to `Object / Array`, or something else?  Wasn't there a pixel array at some point?

[edit] caniuse says IE10 and Opera Mini don't support Uint8ClampedArray, so... ?

Comment: Wouldn't `"Uint8ClampedArray" in window ? new Uint8ClampedArray([]) : []` be OK?

Comment: @RGraham -- I don't know, that's why I'm asking :)  I don't know if every browser that supports Uint8ClampedArrays actually uses it for their canvas implementation, and I don't know know if there are other fallbacks.

Comment: Ah, I understand the question now! Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Is the purpose here to "be" backwards compatible, or is it purely out of interest?

Comment: @Amit -- It's to be backwards compatible to a feasible level.

Comment: Then why not stick with the older standard? Surely it is supported by newer browsers... Unless I miss something, it's not that there is a big difference between the 2 options

Comment: @Amit -- nope.  Chrome complains if I don't give it that exact structure.  I'm trying to figure out if other browsers will complain in different ways.

Comment: Haaa! that's quite surprising... so if someone built a site say... 1 year ago (not sure about timeline), it won't work on current chrome?

Comment: @Amit -- I don't think it's a very common thing to be generating ImageData arrays, but yeah.  Last time I seriously worked with canvas was ~5 years ago, so it changed sometime between then and now :)

Comment: @Kaiido -- I can't make changes to the clone because I need to resize it and the Uint8ClampedArray implementation in Chrome at least has no way to modify size.  Moz specs say there are, but either they're not implemented or they're not agreed upon specs.

Comment: To simplify my use case, I'm resizing an image (it's much more complicated, so anything like having canvas rescale it isn't an option)

Comment: Too slow ;)  I need to push and slice array data.  If I do it directly on a `Uint8ClampedArray` via Array prototypes (`[].slice.call(ary, ...)`). it's far slower than doing it on a normal array.  If you happen to be curious, I'm implementing a real-time content-aware image sizing algorithm.  It works great in Chrome, I'm just trying to figure out backwards compatibility :)

Answer (score 2):

When calling `ctx.getImageData()`, [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-imagedata-width) require the UserAgent to return a [TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) without specifying which type. [The support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray#Browser_compatibility) for TypedArray start with IE10. But, like in IE9, the data property of the [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/ImageData) object is a `CanvasPixelArray`, which has no Constructor method available.

But anyway, the best and *IMK* only cross-browser way to get the correct ArrayBuffer needed  for `ImageData` Object, is to call [`ctx.createImageData(width,height)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createImageData).

Then you can get its `data` array and you are sure its type will be correct.